# Is there any way to show embedded google map in streamlit app?

Tags: python, streamlit

I want to embed google map in my streamlit app. Below is the code:

```
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as components

# embed streamlit docs in a streamlit app
components.iframe("https://www.google.com/maps/")
```

But its showing below output:

[image]

So is there any other way I can do this or importing google maps to your streamlit app is not doable because of paid google services?

Please guide me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Make a research on streamlit and folium.